# CSS Modules with AntD Components

Tags: css, frontend, antd, web-frontend, css-modules

Why cant I style antd components using css module classes?

[(https://i.stack.imgur.com/EezvB.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EezvB.png)
I have to !important property to override antd styles

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Antd Button component has a default property font-weight: 400 so how can I override it with CSS module class to font-weight: 300

Comment: I have a button class in Component.module.scss like this .button { font-weight: 300}